# Using Flask's jsonify displays é as Ã©

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask, utf-8

`jsonify('é')` doesn't print what I expect. Instead of `é`, I see `Ã©`.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False

@app.route('/')
def test():
    return jsonify('é')
```

The encoding of the script is UTF-8. UTF-8 JSON encoding is supposed to be activated by `JSON_AS_ASCII = False`.

Comment: Please give me a hand I do any things but not work
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59956151/flask-response-with-arabic-text-is-not-readable?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: for Flask 2.3+, use `app.json.ensure_ascii = False` (instead of app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're viewing the representation of the dumped data. Since you've disabled `JSON_AS_ASCII`, you get two UTF-8 bytes rather than an ASCII-compatible Unicode escape. JSON is still UTF-8, regardless of which representation you choose, but it is typically safer to stick with the default.

Whatever you're using to view the data is misinterpreting the bytes as Latin-1, not UTF-8. Tell whatever you're viewing the data with that it's UTF-8, and it will look correct. Load the data from JSON and you will see that it is still correct.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, json

app = Flask('example')
app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = True  # default

with app.app_context():
    print(jsonify('é').data)  # b'"\\u00e9"\n', Unicode escape

app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False

with app.app_context():
    print(jsonify('é').data)  # b'"\xc3\xa9"\n', UTF-8 bytes

# you're viewing the bytes as Latin-1
print(b'\xc3\xa9'.decode('latin1'))  # Ã©

# but it's UTF-8
print(b'\xc3\xa9'.decode('utf8'))  # é

# JSON is always UTF-8
print(json.loads(b'"\\u00e9"\n')  # é
print(json.loads(b'"\xc3\xa9"\n')  # é
```

Answer (score 2):

For [Flask 2.3+](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/changes/#version-2-3-0), the configuration way is changed.

Use `app.json.ensure_ascii` (instead of `app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII']`)

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.json.ensure_ascii = False  # <-- this line saves the day
app.json.mimetype = "application/json; charset=utf-8"  # <-- this could be also useful

@app.route('/')
def test():
    return jsonify('é')
```