# Flask response with Arabic text is not readable

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, encoding

i want send arabic words with ajax:

client  side:

```
 $.ajax({
        data: {
              TblName: TblName,
            ID:ID,
            NewName:"اسم المستخدم موجود بالفعل"
        },
        type: 'POST',

        url: '/edit'  
                })
.done(function (data) {...
```

server side(flask):

```
@app.route('/EditName',methods=['POST'])   
def EditName():
    ID = request.form['ID']
    NewNameAfterEdit = request.form['NewName']
    print(NewNameAfterEdit ) #  ans is ??????
```

When I send Arabic text it is not properly encoded, it returns **??????????** but when I send english text, everything is ok.
When I print NewNameAfterEdit I get ???? .

`print(NewNameAfterEdit ) # ans is ??????`

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set flask's configuration **[JSON_AS_ASCII](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#JSON_AS_ASCII)**, to `False`.

Comment: i set   `app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False`   but not work.

Comment: would you mind sharing with us your `app.py` content, or at least how you set your configurations

Comment: my app is simple I write in my question. is that all.

Comment: when i print ans  i get ???? . `print(NewNameAfterEdit ) #  ans is ??????`

Comment: i run my app with cmd and  cmd  cant show utf-8. but with py charm is ok and display true.